# Drupal + Google sign in

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-commerce, google-signin

I'm using Drupal 7 with Commerce. I'm not a good coder but I can read it.
I want to integrate Google+ sign in to my website. 
I have followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/). Created a block with the [script](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/), added the meta to my html.tpl.php
How do I retrive the user's information to be added my user list?

At the moment, users are asked to logon at checkout. They can log in with google signin but once they are sign in, drupal asks again for registration.

Cheers